# How to enable a PACKAGECONFIG feature in an image in bitbake?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Suppose, we have a few features in a recipe as shown in the [examples](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PACKAGECONFIG). Suppose this is written in `meta-somelayer/recipes-functions/functions/functions_git.bb`

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "f1 f2 f3 ..."
     PACKAGECONFIG[f1] = "\
                          --with-f1, \
                          --without-f1, \
                          build-deps-for-f1, \
                          runtime-deps-for-f1, \
                          runtime-recommends-for-f1, \
                          packageconfig-conflicts-for-f1 \
                          "
     PACKAGECONFIG[f2] = "\
                         ... and so on and so on ...
```

How do I enable feature `f1` in my own layer in an image. Suppose I have a layer `meta-mylayer`.

I tried creating a `.bbappend` file in `meta-mylayer/recipes-myrecipes/functions/functions_%.bbappend` and including `PACKAGECONFIG_append = "f1"`, but I suppose that just adds more features to the existing PACKAGECONFIG feature. How do I **select** a feature from a recipe of another layer in my layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a feature to be included to a particular image, add a `.bbappend` file a particular hierarchy in that `meta-` layer of that image. For example, I would add a `.bbappend` file in `meta-mylayer/recipes-myrecipes/functions/functions_%.bbappend`. Then, in that `.bbappend`, I would include:

```
IMAGE_FEATURES += f1
```

to include the `f1` PACKAGECONFIG feature from the `function` recipe.

Comment: Should that instead be `PACKAGECONFIG += "f1"`? It's what I had to do in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to crate a bbappend for that recipe and do it there.