# When defining a Bitbake recipe, how does PACKAGECONFIG... work?

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake, yocto-dunfell

I have two Bitbake recipes and I'm using [Dunfell Yocto](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.29/index.html).

Both recipes `inherit cmake`, ie. `poky/meta/classes/cmake.bbclass`. As I understand it, this CMake Bitbake class effectively just wraps the CMake config, build, and install commands in Yocto/Bitbake-speak -- Bitbake steps `do_configure()`, `do_compile()`, and `do_install()`.

One of my recipes is a library. The other recipe is for the main executable, which `DEPENDS` on the library recipe. The executable needs the `async` option turned on in the library, which does it using a CMake define, `CMAKE_TURN_ON_ASYNC=libasync` when building the library.

To do that in my library recipe, I have found I could go several ways. The easiest I think is to just force my recipe to turn on the `async` option by using `EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DCMAKE_TURN_ON_ASYNC=libasync"`. However, since the library has the ability to turn it on and off in CMake, it seems only good practice and due diligence to provide that option to the Bitbake recipe.

So [I'm trying](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.29/dev-manual/dev-manual-common-tasks.html?highlight=packageconfig) to use the [`PACKAGECONFIG`](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.29/ref-manual/ref-variables.html#term-PACKAGECONFIG) feature [to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64957426/2125392) and failing repeatedly [despite giving](https://yocto.yoctoproject.narkive.com/BQDPnD8s/so-how-does-packageconfig-really-work) my [best effort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76008046/2125392) to figure it out [with both research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313645/2125392) and just trial and error. So maybe it's a fair time to ask the community.

The canonical example from the Variables Glossary starts with this. And I feel this is most likely where I'm going wrong, since `=` and `?=` and `??=` always throw me for a loop:

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "f1 f2 f3 ..."
```

I take this to mean that, both *in* and *for* my current recipe, I'm both *defining* and *turning on* features `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` (unless otherwise set previously by a `=` or `?=`). So, effectively, this recipe will have all these features turned on by default.

Assuming that's right, I came up with this to add to my `lib-with-async-option` recipe:

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "async"
PACKAGECONFIG[async] ="\
    -DCMAKE_TURN_ON_ASYNC=libasync, \
    -DCMAKE_TURN_ON_ASYNC=, \
    libasync \
"
```

Which, as I understand it, will effectively both define and turn on the `async` feature for this recipe, and thus add the `-DCMAKE_TURN_ON_ASYNC=libasync` to the configure script, and add `libasync` to the `DEPENDS` for this recipe.

To my second, executable recipe, I just add:

```
DEPENDS += "lib-with-async-option"
```

And that's it -- the executable recipe will get both `lib-with-async-option` and `libasync` added to its dependency tree, and compile `lib-with-async-option` with the `async` feature turned on.

Well, from the console output, it doesn't seem to work, though as with most things in Yocto/Bitbake, I can't say that for sure. The executable compiles fine, but then fails at the linking stage, with tell-tale signs that it's missing the `libasync` library. I thought I'd come up for air for a sanity check before further troubleshooting.

Am I using the `PACKAGECONFIG` feature correctly to both define and enable a feature by default for my `lib-with-async-option` recipe?

I don't see `async` in the [list of common features](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.29/ref-manual/ref-features.html?highlight=features), but I wonder if I'm stomping on one not defined there? Or do I need to be setting `async` in `MACHINE_FEATURES`, `DISTRO_FEATURES`, or `IMAGE_FEATURES`?